# Storing custom path to images

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am using quite complicated path for user images which is:

`\public\files\assets\images\user-profile`

My question is, can I store it somewhere in laravel, maybe in `.env` file or sth and store it there as `$userImagePath`, so I don't have to rewrite the same path and just use `$userImagePath`. I think it will be safer/more secure solution.

Comment: Of course you can! You might want to do it together with a new config file

Comment: You should store user assets in `storage` not in `public`